# How to convert a custom block with a RichText multiline element to use innerBlocks in Gutenberg instead?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I've have started seeing the following notice in the web developer console when editing posts in Gutenberg:

> *wp.blockEditor.RichText multiline prop is deprecated since version 6.1 and will be removed in version 6.3. Please use nested blocks (InnerBlocks) instead.*

I am unsure how I would go about converting my custom static Gutenberg block that currently uses `<RichText>` with the multiline property into a `<div>` with `<InnerBlocks />` that still honor the original functionality that I built. This is a simplified example of what the `edit()` function currently looks like for the block:

```
edit: ( props ) => {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps( { className: 'custom-cta p-0 mb-0' } );
    const { attributes: { blurb }, setAttributes, className, isSelected } = props;

    return (
      <div { ...blockProps }>
          <RichText
              tagName="div"
              multiline="p"
              className="custom-cta__blurb w-100"
              translate-name="blurb"
              onChange={ value => setAttributes( { blurb: value } ) }
              placeholder={ __( 'Subtext goes here (optional)', 'hello-tools' ) }
              value={ blurb }
              allowedFormats={ [ 'core/bold', 'core/italic' ] }
              focusOnInsert={ false }
              />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might come fairly close to what you are looking for. Try it - you might have to add some more attributes/settings and possibly CSS to get the exact result you are looking for.
This will not be able to replace your current block - so what I mean is, it is not backwards compatible, since it is a totally new block.

````
/**
 * @see ./edit.js
 */
    edit: () => {
        // define which blocks to show when the block gets inserted
        const TEMPLATE = [['core/paragraph']];
        // define what blocks are allowed to be used
        let allowedBlocks = ['core/paragraph'];

        const blockProps = useBlockProps({className: 'my-custom-class'});

        return (
            <div {...blockProps}>
                   <div className={'custom-cta__blurb w-100'}>
                        <InnerBlocks
                            allowedBlocks={allowedBlocks}
                            template={TEMPLATE}
                            // false will let the user add and move the blocks
                            templateLock={false}
                        />
                   </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Thanks @frizzant, would there be a way to get this to be backwards compatible via a migrate() function inside a deprecated object?

Comment: Since it is a separate block, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is why does it have to be a separate block? Why not retrofit the existing one?

Comment: @Kory this is purely because the content you already have with the richtext, can not be converted to innerblocks. So you will lose that content.
So if you don't want to lose it, I would create a separate block. If it doesn't matter, you can choose either of those options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, that is certainly a pain that the Wordpress team would force developers/users to move on from using a <RichText> component without providing a suitable way to migrate without losing content and being backwards compatible.

Comment: @Kory I think you misunderstood, this has nothing to do with how someone implemented it, it is because it is technically totally different. I mean perhaps I am wrong, but to my knowledge this is how it would be done.

Comment: Yeah I just might not be understanding what you're saying. What I'm gathering is that it's not possible to convert the existing block, which means I have to make a new one, that is similar, but utilizes the <InnerBlocks> as you outline above. AND, we'd have to manually go into every post to add the new block and remove the old one or write an involved script to loop through posts and do this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I cant contribute to the discussion under the solution above, but I believe Frizzant is mistaken. Wordpress has included a solution in their [list item block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/list/edit.js) on GitHub, but I do not understand how to implement it.